# Where do I find code for transaction signing?

Tags: signing

I am trying to implement signing in python, but I can't really find any example of signing data (e.g. SIG_1_...) anywhere. ANyone has links to examples?

Basically, I want to sign it 'manually', using python, not cleos and etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Refer to [eospy](https://github.com/eosnewyork/eospy/blob/ed55d652/eospy/keys.py#L160).

EOSIO also uses secp256k1 like Bitcoin or Ethereum, so you can sign a transaction manually, but you should know its encoding convention. Its signature consists of `SIG_K1_` prefix and WIF-encoded BASE58 string. Unlike Bitcoin or Ethereum, EOSIO demands a [canonical](https://github.com/eosnewyork/eospy/blob/ed55d652/eospy/keys.py#L137-L143) signature, which is more restrict than `low-s` signature.

Comment: Unfortunately, eospy doesn't help me. Signatures, that it provides, don't work for WAX network: for some reason it's longer, then the signature, needed in WAX, so WAX node API returns an error. I was trying to use only first 65 bytes of signature it provides, but it didn't work out neither

Comment: I was also trying to use `ecdsa` module, and make signature,  by signing SHA-256'ed data by it (using `ecdsa.SigningKey.from_string(WIF, ecdsa.SECP256k1, hashlib.sha256)`,
But it didn't work niether

Comment: waxjs uses eosjs directly for signing a transaction. I don't think there is a significant difference between eos and wax. You should distinguish 65 bytes signature binary from its encoded (stringified) form.

Comment: you can try to ask the same question on the telegram eosio devs channel: https://t.me/joinchat/0uhWYfXVpPlkNTA1

Answer (score 1):

if you want to see how signing is done in eosio these can be two starting points (none of them are python samples):

https://github.com/EOSIO/eos/blob/26a4d285d0be1052d962149e431eb81500782991/plugins/wallet_plugin/wallet_manager.cpp#L228

https://github.com/EOSIO/eosjs/blob/31ac222bcb1c72830ab3f45c55edddf73805f101/src/eosjs-webauthn-sig.ts#L23

for a python sample try this:
https://github.com/eosnewyork/eospy/blob/ed55d652f5dcc9e45917273e6bc14b37791e772d/eospy/keys.py#L163